# API not receiving information with @PostMapping, but with @RequestMapping yes. Spring Boot, Kotlin, REST API

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin

I'm trying to save a new 'proyecto' through postman.

I'm using:

- Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE. Kotlin 1.2.71 Java 8.

I used the @PostMapping annotation but it sends me nulls, but if I use @RequestMapping it works correctly. *When I try one way or another I comment the code, to avoid conflicts.*

**ProyectoController.kt**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proyectos")
class  ProyectoController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var proyectoService : ProyectoService

    //Not working
    @PostMapping("/")
    fun createProyecto(proyecto: Proyecto): Proyecto {
        return proyectoService.createProyecto(proyecto)
    }

    //Working
    @RequestMapping("/", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
    fun createProyeto2(@RequestBody proyecto: Proyecto): Proyecto{
        return proyectoService.createProyecto(proyecto)
    }
}
```

**Proyecto.kt**

```
@Document(collection = "proyectos")
@TypeAlias("proyecto")
data class Proyecto (
        @Id
        var id: String?,
        var nombre: String,
        var area: String,
        var fecha:String
)
```

**Postman request with @PostMapping**
[image]

**Postman request with @RequestMapping** 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there was a minor missing annotation; `@RequestBody` in your problematic endpoint. Try to have;

```
@PostMapping("/")
fun createProyecto(@RequestBody proyecto: Proyecto): Proyecto {
    return proyectoService.createProyecto(proyecto)
}
```